# Issue in Typing a class with Flowjs

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have the following code that I'm attempting to type with ***Flow***

```
type Metadata = {
   currentPage: string,
};
type State = {
    result: {
        metadata: Metadata,
    }
}

type EmptyObject = {};
type Test = Metadata | EmptyObject;

class HelperFn {
    state: State;
    metadata: Test;
    constructor(state: State) {
        this.state = state;

        if (state && state.result && state.result.metadata) {
            this.metadata = state.result.metadata;
        } else {
            this.metadata = {};
        }
    }
    getCurrentPageNumber() {
        return this.metadata.currentPage;
    }
}
```

I've created *Types* that I'm assigning later on. In my class, I assign the type *Test* to **metadata**. Metadata can be either an *object* with properties or an *empty object*. When declaring the function `getCurrentPageNumber`, the linter Flow tells me that it

```
cannot get 'this.metadata.currentPage' because property 'currentPage' is missing in EmptyObject
```

Looks like Flow only refers to the `emptyObject`. What is the correct syntax to tell Flow that my object can either be with properties or just empty?

Answer (score 1):

Since `metaData` can be empty, Flow is correctly telling you that `this.metadata.currentPage` may not exist. You could wrap it in some sort of check like

```
if (this.metadata.currentPage) {
    return this.metadata.currentPage
} else {
    return 0;
}
```

To get it to work properly.

Comment: i can't do that, i need specifically an empty object as defensive code